# What does process.env.wifi_interface do?

Tags: github, wifi, electron

While reading someone's code on Github's electron, I came across the line
`var wifi_interface = process.env.wifi_interface`
What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is copying an environment variable to a local variable. Any software can set environment variables but going by the name I'd suggest it is a variable that the user should set in their shell prior to running the software to define the device node of the wifi hardware (ie: /dev/eth0 or equivalent) that the software should communicate with.

```
export WIFI_INTERFACE=/dev/eth0
```

Windows also supports environment variables usually set via the "System" control panel.

If you want a more specific answer you'll really need to look at the source code and/or documentation.